# Difference between copying reference of a class and copying value

Tags: c#, class, copy, value-type, reference-type

For an experiment, I tried this :

(1) Create 100000 classes, each of them wrapping a double variable

---This is the experiment part---

(2) Measured performance of two methods by running 100000 times :

- create a double[] and assign the value of wrapped variables.
- create a class[] and assign the reference of wrapping class.

The above may confuse you, so I am attaching the code :

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int length = 100000;
    Test test = new Test(length);

    Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopwatch.Start();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        test.CopyValue();
        //test.CopyReference(); //test.CopyValue(); or test.CopyReference();

    stopwatch.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine("RunTime : {0} ", stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

class DoubleWrapper
{
    public double value = 0.0;
}

class Test
{
    DoubleWrapper[] wrapper;

    public void CopyValue()
    {
        double[] x = new double[wrapper.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < wrapper.Length; i++)
            x[i] = wrapper[i].value;
    }

    public void CopyReference()
    {
        DoubleWrapper[] x = new DoubleWrapper[wrapper.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < wrapper.Length; i++)
            x[i] = wrapper[i];
    }

    public Test(int length)
    {
        wrapper = new DoubleWrapper[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
            wrapper[i] = new DoubleWrapper();
    }
}
```

The result is as follows :

test.CopyValue() : 56890 (millisec)

test.CopyReference() : 66688 (millisec)

(built with release configuration and ran exe)

I tried several times, but the result doesn't change much.
So I concluded that CopyReference() takes longer time.

---

But I hardly understand why. Here is the question :

I thought that, regardless of CopyValue() or CopyReference(), what my machine does is "Copying a number in memory" though one is double value and the another is reference to a class. So there should not be meaningful difference in performance, but the fact is not.

Then what is the difference between copying a value and copying a reference?
Does copying a reference do more thing than copying a value?

(When passing a reference without ref keyword, isn't it true that reference is copied as if it were value? What I am saying is that,

```
ClassA x = new ClassA();
ClassA y = x;
```

means making a copy of "reference of x" and then assigning to variable y, consequently y = null doesn't affect x at all. Is this true?)

If I am working with wrong assumptions, please let me know what I am wrong with.

I appreciate your help and advice.

-

I guessed that GC might have some impact, but turning off GC by TryStartNoGCRegion(Int64) doesn't change the conclusion.
(both become faster, but still CopyReference() is slower.)

Comment: SeM thanks, I edited it.

Comment: _"means making a copy of "reference of x" and then assigning to variable y, consequently y = null doesn't affect x at all. Is this true?)"_ by assigning `x` to `y` you will assign the value of `x` (which is a reference) to `y`, so they will have same reference, but if you assign `null` to `y`, it will not change `x`, cause you are just assigning `null` to `y`'s value. But if you for example have some properties inside you `ClassA` and change it by accessing through `y.Property1 = 10`, it will affect `x.Property1`.

Comment: SeM thank you for the comment. I understood. I think I made you confused with bad English.(I am not native.) The expression "reference of x" was bad one. As you pointed out, value of x is reference. What I tried to say was "value of x, which is a reference, is copied to y".

Comment: that's correct.

Comment: One thing that might be worth testing is how the timings change if you move the `new DoubleWrapper[wrapper.Length];` out of the `CopyValue` method (same for the other case) and instead supply an already newed up array to the method. The way your test works now, the time of the array constructors are part of your total time. Not sure if it will make much difference but might be worth testing.

Answer (score 0):

> means making a copy of "reference of x" and then assigning to variable
>   y, consequently y = null doesn't affect x at all. Is this true?

That's correct - you made a *copy* of reference.

Now, what about why your implementation of `CopyReference` is slower.

You have to do performance analysis to get real insight about it, but on top of my head:

You're creating a new instance of `DoubleWrapper` *reference type*, inside that method. 
Remember, that `C#` is not "zero-cost abstraction" language, like `C/C++/Rust` might be. 
Creating an instance of, even simple reference type, that does nothing more than a simple wrapper over a primitive type, suppose to cost you more. Because that instance has more in it than a simple `double` value - the size of `DoubleWrapper`object will not be equal to 8 bytes.

Answer (score -1):

Reading about the stack and the heap may help you understand. if you copy a reference, you essentially copy the pointer showing to the actual object in the heap, and if that actual object changes, those changes are shown on every thing that references that object.

If you do a "deep copy", or a clone (like when implementing IClonable) you will duplicate that data in the stack and create a pointer to it, thus not beeing dependant on the original object any longer.

I hope this explanation helps you a little bit? See this for some information https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/C-Sharp-heaping-vs-stacking-in-net-part-i/ on the stack and heap.